# Create a filter function for monads in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

Suppose we have a filter function.

`filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]`

Assume our `a -> m Bool` function is as such:

```
p :: Integer -> Maybe Bool
p n | n > 0 = Just True
    | n < 0 = Just False
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

In the example, `m` is Maybe.

I want to create the filterM function such that:

```
filterM p [2,−4,1] = Just [2,1]

filterM p [2,0,−4,1] = Nothing
```

Essentially this filterM is filter, but for monads.

Here is my implementation of it. It doesn't work, and I have a couple of questions about it.

```
filterM p [] = pure []
filterM p (x : xs) | p x == Just True = x : (filterM p xs)
                   | p x == Just False = filterM p xs
                   | otherwise = Nothing
```

Firstly, why doesn't it work. It says `Couldn't match type m with Maybe m is a rigid type variable`.

```
  Expected type: m Bool
  Actual type: Maybe Bool
```

In my function, I hardcoded "Maybe" as `m`, but how do I make this more generic?

I would use do notation but it doesn't seem like best option since there is recursion.

Comment: Note that `filterM` (for general applicatives, not just `Maybe`) is already defined in `Control.Monad`.

Comment: Yes, changing the function name to something else still gives same result

Comment: `p x` has type `m Bool` so you can't match it against `Just True` which has type `Maybe Bool`

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.  The first is that you've given the type signature:

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

and then defined `filterM` with `m` specialized to `Maybe` (because you use `Just` and `Nothing` in your definition).  When Haskell deduces that `m` must be `Maybe`, this results in an error.  The type `m` is "rigid" in the sense that it was supplied by you in a type signature, and rigid types have to stay general; it's a conflict if they become less polymorphic than specified.  You can generate a similar error message by writing:

```
badId :: a -> Int
badId x = x
```

Clearly, `a` is `Int`, and so it's a conflict that the rigid (programmer-specified) type `a` was determined to match `Int` during type checking.

However, even if you fix your type signature:

```
filterM :: (a -> Maybe Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
filterM p [] = pure []
filterM p (x : xs) | p x == Just True = x : (filterM p xs)
                   | p x == Just False = filterM p xs
                   | otherwise = Nothing
```

you'll still get an error message.  You're mixing up monadic actions and values in your code.  In the expression:

```
x : filterM p xs
```

you're applying the operator `(:) :: b -> [b] -> [b]` to the types `a` and `Maybe [a]`, so it doesn't typecheck ("Couldn't match expected type `Maybe [a]` with actual type `[a]`.")

You'll need to replace `x : filterM p xs` with something like:

```
case filterM p xs of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just xs' -> Just (x : xs')
```

Comment: The `case` you recommend in your last sentence is more easily written using Maybe's Functor instance: `(x :) <$> filterM p xs`

Answer (score 2):

Your type error comes from specifying a type signature that is polymorphic (`m`) but an implementation that’s specialised to a particular `m` (`Maybe`)—you’ve told the typechecker this function works `forall m`, but it doesn’t.

In order to generalise this, you need to solve two other minor issues: first, you can’t use a general monadic condition in a guard, only a pure condition. Second, you can’t use the `:` operator on `x` and the result of `filterM`, since `:` is pure but you’ve given it a monadic argument.

For the monadic version, you can use `do` notation:

```
filterM p [] = pure []
filterM p (x : xs) = do
  px <- p x  -- Run the condition
  if px
    then do
      xs' <- filterM p xs  -- Run the recursive action
      pure (x : xs')       -- Build the result
    else filterM p xs
```

> I would use do notation but it doesn’t seem like best option since there is recursion.

It’s perfectly fine to write recursive monadic code, with or without `do` notation, as you can see here—you just need to be aware of when you’re *executing actions* versus *evaluating expressions*.

The `otherwise` case in your original code is handled implicitly by the monadic bindings; if `p x` returns `Nothing` for `m ~ Maybe` then the whole computation will return `Nothing`.

If you want to avoid `do` notation, you can use the monad/functor combinators directly:

```
filterM p [] = pure []
filterM p (x : xs)
  = p x >>= \ px -> if px
    then (x :) <$> filterM p xs
    else filterM p xs
```

While `<$>` (`fmap`) is nicer here, I would personally prefer to use `do` over `>>=` with a lambda.

This can also be simplified somewhat by factoring out the repetition of `filterM p` and, since `p` doesn’t change within a call to `filterM`, just referencing it in a helper function.

```
filterM p = go
  where
    go [] = pure []
    go (x : xs) = do
      px <- p x

      -- Or: if px then (x :) <$> go xs else go xs
      xs' <- go xs
      pure (if px then x : xs' else xs')
```

Comment: How is it possible to do `x: xs'`? `xs'` is a monadic value, wheras `x` is just an integer

Comment: @KSplitX: In all of these examples, `xs'` is a pure value of type `[a]`; the recursive call `filterM p xs` is a monadic action of type `m [a]`, but we *bind* its result to `xs'` using a bind statement (`<-`) within `do` or the bind operator (`>>=`). Specifically, `xs' <- filterM p xs; pure (x : xs')` = `filterM p xs >>= \ xs' -> pure (x : xs')`—the key is that we *chain* `filterM p xs :: m [a]` with a function of type `[a] -> m [a]` to produce a combined action of type `m [a]`. Within that function, we can use the value directly.

Comment: @KSplitX: An important thing to note is that a value of type `m a` is *not* a value of type `a` “tagged” with a monadic context of type `m`—rather, it’s a value representing an *action* that may produce values of type `a` when executed, and may perform effects according to the particular `m`. (Some monads such as `Maybe`, `[]`, and `Either` do happen to be containers, but many such as `IO`, `Cont`, and `STM` are not, so the “action” interpretation is more general.)